# How do I get the date of RSS Feed?

Tags: rss, timestamp, getdate

I have RSS feed link, but I need to obtain date from it. Then determine whether to do something based on how close it is to the current time.

```
$date = Get_RSS_Date(); 
$currenttime = getdate();
if $data = too far away from $currenttime then don't display RSS feed.
```

Make sense?

Comment: What language are you using? Have you checked the RSS specification?

Comment: i figured it out - just have to pull all of the info with the feed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Magpie_RSS function which will return an array of the RSS properties, and PubDate key contains the timestamp.